# Como colocar os valores do JSON em um gráfico no HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, json

```js
// Classe para chamar o Json.
function json(){
 var qtd;
 var retorno;

 // Resgatar valores.
 json.prototype.resgatarValores = function(){
  $('#resultado').html('Carregando dados...');

  // Estrutura de resultado.
  $.getJSON('/webpro/webadm/lncidjson', function(data){
   this.qtd = data.usuarios.length - 1;
   this.valore = '';
   this.label = '';

   for (i = 0; i < this.qtd; i++){
    if(i == (this.qtd - 1)) {
     this.valore += data.usuarios[i].valor;
     this.label += data.usuarios[i].descr;
    } 
    else {
     this.valore += data.usuarios[i].valor + ',';
     this.label += data.usuarios[i].descr + ',';
    }
   }

   $('#valor').html(this.valore);
   $('#label').html(this.label);
  });

 }

}

// Objeto.
var obj = new json();
obj.resgatarValores();
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial;
}

pre.code {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 2px dashed gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="RGraph/libraries/RGraph.common.core.js" ></script>
<script src="RGraph/libraries/RGraph.common.dynamic.js" ></script>
<script src="RGraph/libraries/RGraph.common.tooltips.js" ></script>
<script src="RGraph/libraries/RGraph.line.js" ></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 google.load("jquery", "1.3.2", {uncompressed:true});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="json.class.js"></script>

<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../excanvas/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->

<p style="margin-left:50em;"><title>Cotação USD x BRL</title></p>

<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
<meta name="Descrição" content="Cotação do Dolar de Acordo com o Real" />
 
</head>
<body>

<h2></h2>

<canvas id="cvs" width="900" height="300">[No canvas support]</canvas>

  </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("jquery", "1.3.2", {uncompressed:true});
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="json.class.js"></script>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../excanvas/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
    
    <p style="margin-left:50em;"><title>Cotação USD x BRL</title></p>
    
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
    <meta name="Descrição" content="Cotação do Dolar de Acordo com o Real" />
     
</head>
<body>

    <h2></h2>

    <canvas id="cvs" width="900" height="300">[No canvas support]</canvas>
    
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
  
            var data     =  [document.getElementById('valor').value];
            var tooltips = [];
            //var data     = [2.59,2.60,2.40,2.67,1.78];
 
    
            // Create the tooltips
            for (var i=0; i<data.length; i+=1) {
                tooltips[i] = '1 USD = ' + String(data[i] + ' Reais')
            }

            var line = new RGraph.Line({
                id: 'cvs',
                data: data,
                options: {
                    tooltips: {
                        self: tooltips,
                        highlight: false
                    },
                    colors: ['#058DC7'],
                    filled: true,
                    fillstyle: 'rgba(229,243,249,0.5)',
                    tickmarks: 'filledcircle',
                    background: {
                        grid: {
                            vlines: false,
                            border: false,
                            autofit: {
                                numhlines: 10
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    shadow: false,
                    linewidth: 3,
                    gutter: {
                        left: 50,
                        right: 20
                    },
                    numxticks: 0,
                    ylabels: {
                        count: 5
                    },
                    axis: {
                        color: '#aaa'
                    },
                    text: {
                        color: '#aaa'
                    },
                    labels: ['21/01','22/01','23/01','24/01','25/01']
                }
            })
            
            RGraph.ISOLD ? line.draw() : line.trace2();
  
        })
  
    </script>
 
 <div id="valor"></div>        
 <div id="label"></div>
 
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Poderia elaborar sua pergunta um pouquinho mais? O que você quer dizer com 'mandar para um JavaScript'? Eu imagino que você esteja se referindo à coleção `data.usuarios`, correto?

Comment: Tenho esse Array e quero pegar o resultado do mesmo em javascript !

Comment: VocÊ quer trabalhar com o retorno do $.getJSON é isso? Tá um pouco confusa sua pergunta.

Comment: Elisson, JSON nada mais é do que uma notação baseada em objetos JavaScritp (JavaScript Object Notation). Se o JSON retornado após a execução do método `getJSON` estiver correto, então o parâmetro `data` contém o próprio objeto JSON e a propriedade `data.usuarios` já contém o array. Não é necessário fazer nada para converter esse valor.

Comment: Edite seu código e mantenha apenas as partes relevantes à pergunta.

Comment: Informe qual biblioteca está usando para gerar os gráficos, fica complicado ter que adivinhar.

Comment: As bibliotecas usadas estão no código que foi editado como pedido !

Comment: @elisson Você editou o código. Mas agora, qual é a pergunta?

Comment: Meu problema é o seguinte no JavaScript tem a variavel "data" se colocado os valores direteto nela o gráfico funciona normal, mais preciso pegar esses valores do Json. Mas não sei como pegar e mandar para a variavel apartir do Json